# When restoring multiple databases the test aborts but no error is thrown?

Tags: c#, automation, mstest, parallel.foreach

So I have a test framework which is restoring two databases, there are both a `TestInitialisation` and `TestCleanup` methods.

When it was running in `Parallel.ForEach` mode I was getting Thread was Aborting error and no other error so I assumed something with SQL Server was throwing an error and did the restores one after the other instead.

The first restore works fine, the second one while in the middle of creating the connection string is now getting a Thread was Aborting error but I looked further and there is another thread running in the middle of `TestCleanup` so MSTest is closing my test early by aborting the main thread and calling Cleanup without an error being thrown.

What could be causing this if the main test thread is in the middle of doing something else? If I let it run the error I get back is:

> Thread was Aborting

Edit: So it seems this is related to the TestTimeout attribute, but instead of telling me it's timing out, it's just aborting all threads and causing the main thread to throw an error instead?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I feel a bit stupid, I guess this is what happens when you inherit a plate of spaghetti and ask SO before getting to the end of the debugging process.

`TestCleanup` calls some SQL on the database that is currently restoring and so the error thrown there will take precedence over the timout error.

I'll be having a stern word with the author about adding SQL to TestCleanup.